# How to merge multiple csv files (without headers) into one csv file using windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

How do I merge several csv files into one big csv file?

All the csv files have the same number of columns and no headers

Important that I can find the saved file once done

Comment: If you're purely merging the csv files and not doing anything else with them then I'd suggest doing this on the command line for simplicity. What operating system are you using? I can tell you how to do this very easily on Linux or Mac.

Comment: If you check out the following link, it will show you how to read in multiple csv files into one data frame.  You can then write the combined data set to a file. If it is too much to fit into memory, you could modify the solution in the link to write each file out by appending (use option `append = TRUE`). The link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190280/issue-in-loading-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataframe-in-r-using-rbind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows 7:

Command line solution.

1. Make sure that no file contains a header
2. Open command line (`cmd`)
3. Enter correct directory (`cd C:\yourdirectory`)
4. Write (`copy *.csv allcsvsmerged.csv`)

That's it