# My first function in R reading csv's

Tags: r, function

I've learned that if you are to repeat the same thing over and over again it's wise to write a function. Untill now I've come a long way without writing one myself. The `R` ecosystem of packages and its functions has treated me well so far.

I'm trying to do the following. Where the `q1_2018_raw` variable will be replaced with multiple quarters of years 2010 till 2018 so `q1_2010_raw` till `q1_2018_raw`. The only thing that will change is the file within `read_csv()` and the value within `add_column()`. The rest stays the same.

Then I want to bind all the dataframes together with `rbind()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

q1_2018_raw <- read_csv("geluidshinder/bas_meldingen_csv/tabula-bijlage_q1-2018.csv",
                        col_names = c("cluster", "woonplaats", 
                                      "sm_nov", "sm_dec", "sm_jan",
                                      "pm_nov", "pm_dec", "pm_jan",
                                      "am_nov", "am_dec", "am_jan",
                                      "totaal", "snachts", "melders")) %>%
  add_column(kwartaal = "q1_2018", .before = T)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190280/issue-in-loading-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataframe-in-r-using-rbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if I understood your question correctly.

With `csv`being the variable that will hold your csv, `path` being the path where your csv is located, and `column.name` the value in add_column.

```
customcsvreader <- function(csv, path, column.name){
  csv <- read_csv(path,
                  col_names = c("cluster", "woonplaats", 
                                "sm_nov", "sm_dec", "sm_jan",
                                "pm_nov", "pm_dec", "pm_jan",
                                "am_nov", "am_dec", "am_jan",
                                "totaal", "snachts", "melders")) %>%
  add_column(kwartaal= column.name, .before=T))
}
```

example:

```
customcsvreader(q1_2018_raw, "geluidshinder/bas_meldingen_csv/tabula-bijlage_q1-2018.csv", "q1_2018")
```