# R function loops twice?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I wrote a loop which inputs several text files, performs a few functions on each and combines them. I've copied it below and annotated each line. However, the first file in **i** gets read in (and added to my final table) twice!
Also, looking forward to streamline this loop.

```
source_files<-list.files(pattern="_output.txt") # This line finds all file ending with .txt
```

*source_files* from above lists the appropriate files to input in the below loop.

```
for (i in source_files){
    if (!exists("final_table")){
        df_import<-read.table(i, header=FALSE, sep="\t") # reads in each file
        names<-unlist(strsplit(i,"_")) # reformats input file name and parses to 'names'
        df_import$Sample<-names[1] # replaces col[1] header with first part of file name
        df_import$DB<-names[2] # replaces col[1] header with first part of file name
        final_table<-df_import # creates the final table data frame
        rm(df_import) # remove excess df
        }
    if (exists("final_table")){
        df_import<-read.table(i, header=FALSE, sep="\t") # reads in each file
        names<-unlist(strsplit(i,"_")) # reformats input file name and parses to 'names'
        df_import$Sample<-names[1] # replaces col[1] header with first part of file name
        df_import$DB<-names[2] # replaces col[1] header with first part of file name
        final_table <-rbind(final_table, df_import) # Adds to existing final table
        rm(df_import)   
    }
}
```

This loop is working great, except that **final_table** has a duplication - any suggestions?

Comment: You could also initialize `final_table` outside of the `for` loop, removing the need for `if/else` completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you test if the table exists in the first `if`, and if it doesn't it creates it and adds a row to it. So when you get to the second `if`, the table does exist but it adds the row again. Rather than using two `if` statements, use one `if/else`. Also maybe just move the `final_table <-...` lines into the `if` and move the other lines out so you don't have so much repeated code.

Maybe

```
for (i in source_files){
    df_import<-read.table(i, header=FALSE, sep="\t") # reads in each file
    names<-unlist(strsplit(i,"_")) # reformats input file name and parses to 'names'
    df_import$Sample<-names[1] # replaces col[1] header with first part of file name
    df_import$DB<-names[2] # replaces col[1] header with first part of file name
    if (!exists("final_table")){
        final_table<-df_import # creates the final table data frame
    } else {
        final_table <-rbind(final_table, df_import) # Adds to existing final table
    }
    rm(df_import) # remove excess df
}
```

Those there are better ways to do this rather than looping and rbinding each time. See this answer: [What's wrong with my function to load multiple .csv files into single dataframe in R using rbind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190280/whats-wrong-with-my-function-to-load-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataframe)

Comment: That is more streamlined and fixes the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a slightly different approach. It appears the only difference in your `if()` block is what you do with `final_table`. I would probably do something along these lines:

```
#This mimics your list.files() call
list_of_files <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)

#put the guts of your code inside a function
process_file <- function(file) {
  #your stuff goes here - I'm just going to add a random variable named foo      
  file$foo <- rnorm(nrow(file))
  return(file)
}
#use lapply to iterate over your list of files and do.call to bind them together
output <- do.call("rbind", lapply(list_of_files, process_file))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: this is also a good use to lapply() and can be used for other types of for loops, etc. that require processing several data frames. Thanks!